# Wait() is missed by shell

Tags: linux, shell, wait

I was going through some interview question on linux i found

What would happen if shell omitted the wait()??

this one i am not pretty sure what kind behavior shell or kernel show if wait() is missed, Please help.
thanks in adv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the shell would have no means to report the exit code of the processes it forks.

Second, without waiting, zombie processes pile up until the shell exits and they are adopted by `init`.